# Object 'unavailable' in Firefox console

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, getelementsbyclassname

I have a few divs with `class='class_name'`, and also have declared

```
var A = document.getElementsByClassName('class_name');
console.log(A[0]);
```

The Chrome console shows:

```
<div class="class_name"> div 1 </div>
```

The Firefox console shows:

```
<unavailable>
```

What's the issue or what otherwise is the possible cause?

Comment: add firefox version. and a snippet too

Comment: Had similar issue once with Firefox + Firebug. Turns out Firebug is not being maintened anymore, had to switch to [the Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) to get a working console again.

Comment: @Sagar V7 - Firefox version is 52.0.2 (32-bit) - Please explain what you mean by 'snippet' ? Working example in Fiddle or some like that?

Comment: @JiFus -Thnx 4 suggestion - Strange thing is that many other logs in console.log  are showing just fine

Comment: @br00x Same for me, just saying you might want to give it a try. Might also just be another problem of course.

Comment: I have tried it in Chrome and Firefox (48 & 54) - everything is ok. I used the browser's console in both cases.

Answer (score 8):

There are currently four solutions :

1. Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(variable, null, 4))` in place of `console.info(variable)`.  This has the *additional advantage* of catching errors caused by any type of memory management bugs, but it may cause a cyclic redundancy on actual elements when interpolating parent/child elements.  Original solution by me.
2. Use Firefox Web Console (`control+shift+K`, or `Tools->Web Developer->Web Console`) instead of the standard Firefox Browser Console (`control+shift+J`, or `Tools->Web Developer->Browser Console`). *Thanks to **Panos Astithas** for providing this info!*
3. Disable e10s in FF config. Goto `about:config` as an address within Firefox, and set `browser.tabs.remote.autostart` or `loop.remote.autostart` to false. *Thanks to **Janekptacijarabaci** for providing this info!*
4. Revert your FireFox Quantum version.  I uninstalled Firefox 57 and 59 ("Firefox Quantum") and then installed Firefox version 56.0.2.  This fixed the problem for me.  Get it here: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/56.0.2/  Original solution by me.

Firefox Development Ticket: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1136995

**UPDATE :** Problem persists with Firefox v. 59.0.2, and v. 59.0.3.

Comment: OP was not using Firefox 57 to begin with, so changing 4 versions is a wide guess.

Comment: @TylerH: I noted that, but thank you, anyway. =)  Either way, have you tried my solution, or did you have the problem?

Answer (score 7):

Two possible workarounds:

**1)** Use the "Web-Console".
The "Web-Console" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> instead of the "Browser-Console" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) shows the expected output.

**2)** Disable "e10s" multiprocessor support:

```
- about:config
- browser.tabs.remote.autostart = False
```

The Browser-Console will show the expected output if e10s is disabled.

#### Recap (02.01.2018):

The problem still persists in FF 64.0:
in general, objects will be shown as "unavailable" in the Browser-Console.

To reproduce (e10s enabled):

```
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log( 'test' );
        console.log( 123 );
        console.log( [ 1, 2, 3 ] );
        console.log( { x: 'x' } );
        console.log( document.getElementById('myDiv') );
        window.onload = function() {
            console.log( document.getElementById('myDiv') );
        };
    </script>
</head><body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body></html>
```

Output in Browser-Console (wrong output):

```
test
123
<unavailable>
<unavailable>
null
<unavailable>
```

Output in Web-Console (as expected):

```
test
123
Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]
Object { x: "x" }
null
<div id="myDiv">
```

See also:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1136995